# How to create android shell script to edit string in xml

Tags: android, xml, bash, unix

**This is the xml file that I am trying to edit**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<boolean name="public_checkins" value="false" />
<string name="checkins">[{&quot;storeName&quot;:&quot;Rundle Street&quot;,&quot;prize&quot;:&quot;price_fwh&quot;,&quot;checkinTime&quot;:1352717951195,&quot;prizeClaimed&quot;:false,&quot;storeId&quot;:57,&quot;expired&quot;:false},{&quot;storeName&quot;:&quot; Street&quot;,&quot;prize&quot;:&quot;price_fmf&quot;,&quot;checkinTime&quot;:1352717723886,&quot;prizeClaimed&quot;:false,&quot;storeId&quot;:57,&quot;expired&quot;:false}]</string>
*<string name="uuid">30212345-0c1e-dcb-974e-5effa7f016be</string>*
</map>
```

I am trying to create a shell script to edit the the string uuid and replace uuid with a randomly generated sequence of numbers each time i run the script.

Below is the script that I came up with.

```
#!/system/bin/sh

set number=$RANDOM

echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<boolean name="public_checkins" value="false" />
<string name="checkins">[{&quot;storeName&quot;:&quot; Street&quot;,&quot;prize&quot;:&quot;price_fwh&quot;,&quot;checkinTime&quot;:1352717951195,&quot;prizeClaimed&quot;:false,&quot;storeId&quot;:57,&quot;expired&quot;:false},{&quot;storeName&quot;:&quot;Rundle Street&quot;,&quot;prize&quot;:&quot;price_fmf&quot;,&quot;checkinTime&quot;:1352717723886,&quot;prizeClaimed&quot;:false,&quot;storeId&quot;:57,&quot;expired&quot;:false}]</string>
<string name="uuid">302$number-0c1e-dcb-974e-5effa7f016be</string>
</map>
" > /data/data/com.app/shared_prefs/app.xml
```

Comment: String resources are read only you can't edit them. You are coping the string file to app.xml. Is it? If so then what are you trying to accomplished. Instead you can use StringFormat method to generate the string for a format defined in String resource.

Comment: I am trying to echo a random number into the string that exists in app.xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<string name="uuid">302%1$s-0c1e-dcb-974e-5effa7f016be</string>
</map>
```

Now you can use this format to get the string like below

```
String uuid = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.uuid), YourUUIDNumber);
```

You will receive the full string

```
302xxxxxx-0c1e-dcb-974e-5effa7f016be
```

where xxxxxxx is the values which you have passed in the format method of the String.

Comment: This only retrieves the string value but does not write to it.

Answer (score 0):

Perl would be more appropriate for this

```
file=/data/data/com.app/shared_prefs/app.xml
mv $file $file.bak
{
 arr=({0..9} {a..f})
 while IFS=\> read -d\< tag str; do
  if [[ $tag = *'name="uuid"'* ]]; then
   randomstr=
   for ((i=0;i<32;i++)); do
    if ((i%4==0 && i/4>=2 && i/4<6)); then
     randomstr=$randomstr-
    fi
    randomstr=$randomstr${arr[RANDOM%16]}
   done
  printf "%s" "$tag${str:+>}$randomstr<"
  else
   printf "%s" "$tag${str:+>}$str<"
  fi
 done
 printf "%s\n" "$tag>"
} <$file.bak >$file
# rm $file.bak #
```

Comment: But doesn't this create a separate xml file?

Comment: yes, if you need to modify $file `mv $file $file.bak` and `cmd <$file.bak >$file` ; answer was edited